# @Autowiredl bean from external api always nul

Tags: java, spring, autowired, applicationcontext

I have a external jar. There's a AnnotationConfigApplicationContext in it.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan{~~~~~}
public A_config() {
   @Bean
   ~~~~~~
}
```

somewhere

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new 
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ();
ctx.register(A_config());
```

I have another application referring external jar.
This application also have

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan{~~~~~}
public B_config() {
   @Bean
   ~~~~~~
}

AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new 
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ();
ctx.register(A_config());
ctx.register(B_config());
```

When I use ctx.getBean(some.class), some.class in external jar, it's ok.
But I autowired field bean in external jar, it's always null.

Comment: Why dont you just import `A_config` into `B_config` then?

Comment: Should I write an answer then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import your `@Configuration` defined in the external jar into your `@Configuration` of your application like so:

```
@Import(A_config.class)
@Configuration
@ComponentScan{~~~~~}
public B_config() {
   @Bean
   ~~~~~~
}
```